# Postfix logs to remote server

Tags: server, postfix, syslog, smtp, rsyslog

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server, I'm using Postfix as a front-end mailserver, and I would like to send all mail related info, including email addresses, to a remote host. In the file /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf I have added the line:

```
*.*             @192.168.1.21
```

All syslog and smtpd related messages are send to the remote host, however, I'm missing the actual email addresses of the postfix/smtp transactions.

Are there special Postfix or Rsyslog configuration options to achieve this?